# Getting undefined reference errors when compiling

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, compiler-errors, linker

I'm learning SDL2, but when i compile (with gcc) i get these errors:

```
C:\Users\alvel\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgEmjJ0.o:main.c:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `SDL_Init'
C:\Users\alvel\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgEmjJ0.o:main.c:(.text+0x44): undefined reference to `SDL_CreateWindow'
C:\Users\alvel\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgEmjJ0.o:main.c:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to `SDL_DestroyWindow'
C:\Users\alvel\AppData\Local\Temp\ccgEmjJ0.o:main.c:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `SDL_Quit'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
```

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

static const int width = 320;
static const int height = 180;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello, SDL2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, width, height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

(It is indeed completely stolen)

And --probably more importantly-- my Makefile

```
OBJS = main.c

CC = gcc

COMPILER_FLAGS = -Wall -Iinclude

LINKER_FLAGS = -Llib -lSDL2

OBJ_NAME = main.exe

all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(COMPILER_FLAGS) -o build\$(OBJ_NAME) $(LINKER_FLAGS)
```

I'm storing libraries in the "lib" folder and includes in the "include" folder.

I've played around with changing the linker flags such as from `-Llib`  to `-Llib/` , but nothing was worked.

I've now found the problem, seems like i had an old version of gcc.

Comment: You'll probably want to link SDL2main as well. What is actually in the lib directory? Are you sure you have the right libraries for your compiler and target?

Comment: Have you installed SDL in your project's subfolder?

Comment: Typically the file options to link are -lmingw32 -lsdl2main -lsdl2.dll

Comment: @RetiredNinja i tried linking to SDL2Main, did not work. And i'm actually not sure i have the right libraries, but i can't find what i'd guess is the right ones.

Comment: @CGi03 Indeed i have, or at least put the lib files in the lib folder and put the includes in the include folder. I also have the SDL2 dll in the build folder.

Comment: @CGi03 I tried using those linker flags (with locations), did not work. Plus, i don't think i need -lmingw64 since a hello world compiled just fine (when removing sdl libs and includes)

Comment: Well, you could explain where you got the libraries from and what their names are so we can help you.

Comment: @RetiredNinja i got everything from https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/releases/tag/release-2.28.5, the libraries and includes are from SDL2-devel-2.28.5-mingw.zip and the ddl that is in the build folder is from SDL2-2.28.5-win32-x64.zip

Comment: I would suggest some more too: `-lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL_mixer -lSDL_image`